Как вытащить данные о force feedback из игры в python
Допустим я собрался сделать игровой руль на микроконтроллере, я понимаю что должен сделать наверное hid usb устройство типа джойстик. А как получить данные о обратной связи из игры на устройство? можно ли без самого руля как то узнать эти данные программно? знаю что копать нужно в сторону DirectInput, но так ничего и не понял. Интересна любая информация на эту тему, то что есть готовые прошивки я знаю но мне интересно как это работает
